# Error when using Django Rest Framework's APITestCase

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to run some tests for my Django-Rest-Framework API but am stuck on an error.  When I run the following tests, I get the following errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bill\SD\DjangoApps\vidapp\startapp\tests.py", line 21, in test_get_user
    response = self.client.get('/user/1/')
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 473, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 280, in get
    return self.request(**r)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 143, in request
    return super(APIClient, self).request(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 95, in request
    request = super(APIRequestFactory, self).request(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 444, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Test Cases:

```
class UserTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        helper.reset_test_db()

    def test_get_user(self):
        response = self.client.get('/user/1/')
        print response.content
        self.assertEqual(response.data, {'fname':'Generic','lname':'Name','token':'token1'})
```

URL Config:

```
url(r'^user/new/$', 'startapp.views.new_user'),
url(r'^user/1/$', 'startapp.views.get_1'),
```

Views:

```
class get_1(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        user = db_models.User.objects.get(pk=1)
        if(user is not None):
            serial_user = serial.UserSerializer(user)
            return Response(serial_user.data)
        else:
            return Response(status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

I know the view itself works because I tested that separately.  The data is definitely present since helper.reset_test_db() puts it there (I know I should be using fixtures but this is for testing so I went with the simple route). The same error occurs for POST and other commands or when I use Django's TestCase instead of APITestCase. While this is my first time using Django's TestCase, I read both the Django and Django rest documents but can't seem to figure out this issue.

Comment: which DRF version do you use?

Comment: DRF is 2.3.12.  I used pip install so I assume that's the most recent release.  If any of this other information is useful, I'm use django 1.6.2 and python 2.7.5 :: Anaconda 1.7.0.

Comment: @DenisCornehl DRF is 2.3.12. I used pip install so I assume that's the most recent release. If any of this other information is useful, I'm use django 1.6.2 and python 2.7.5 :: Anaconda 1.7.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view in your case is a class-based view.

So you have to add it to the urlconfig with `as_view`:

```
url(r'^user/1/$', startapp.views.get_1.as_view()),
```